# Error struct assignment in if clause (language spec question)

Tags: go, language-specifications

I get an error which I can't explain. Can you help me?

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type mystruct struct {
    a string
}

func main() {

    // ok
    m := mystruct{"a"}
    if m.a == "x" {
        fmt.Println("is x")
    }

    // not ok, error is:
    // ./main.go:20:7: syntax error: cannot use b := mystruct as value
    // ./main.go:23:1: syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body
    if b := mystruct{"x"} ; b.a == "aaa" {
        fmt.Println("is aaa")
    }
}
```

From the language spec:

The expression may be preceded by a [simple statement](https://go.dev/ref/spec#SimpleStmt), which executes before the expression is evaluated.

```
if x := f(); x < y {
    return x
} else if x > z {
    return z
} else {
    return y
}
```

The simple statement can be an [assignment](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignment) (among other things) but I cannot find why `b := mystruct{"x"}` is not an assignment or where the problem is.

Comment: `if b := (mystruct{"x"}) ; b.a == "aaa" {` The first `{` is confusing the parser of the `if` statement, it thinks that's the start of the if's body, you need to use the parentheses to help guide it.

Comment: @mkopriva OK that makes sense. Thank you very much. If you turn it into an answer, I'll happily upvote it and mark it as an answer.